# Formtools username

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a problem with FormTools ([www.formtools.org](http://www.formtools.org)) maybe some of you met with this problem. I need the username to be entered automatically in the form. Actually I use Submission Pre-Parser module to take value about username

```
if (!empty($_POST["username"])) {
    $_POST["FormTools\Sessions::get("account.username")"] = true;
}
```

and next I use custom fields module where i define something like this

```
<input type="text" name="{$NAME}" value="<?php echo $username ?>" class="{$size}{if $highlight} {$highlight}{/if}" id="username" 
{if $maxlength}maxlength="{$maxlength}"{/if} />
 {if $comments}
   <div class="cf_field_comments">{$comments}</div>
 {/if}
```

But the reason look like this

[image]

Maybe some of you can help me how I can to transfer value from

```
FormTools\Sessions::get("account.username")
```

to

```
<input type="text" value="**HERE">
```

Comment: have you tried `{}` before <?php echo $username ?>
somethuing like that 
{<?php echo $username ?>}

Comment: Now I try `value="{<?php echo $username ?>}"`, `value={<?php echo $username ?>}` and I have error https://www.screencast.com/t/PJBewcwS

Comment: just try $username  instead of <?php echo $username ?>

Comment: value="$username" returns https://www.screencast.com/t/ryUEJEjp4WMH

Comment: value=$username returns the same

Comment: value="{$username}" returns empty field

Comment: Maybe is the different solution to insert to value. Maybe should work somethink like this - but not work... `$users = FormTools\Sessions::get("account.username");
$rows = $users->fetchAll();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $_POST["usuername"];
}`

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
The reason was add in config.php `$g_use_smarty_bc = true;` and nextly in Custom Fields modules

```
{php}
    $username = FormTools\Sessions::get("account.username");
    {/php}
    <input readonly type="text" name="{$NAME}" value="{php}echo $username{/php}" class=""                id="username"
   {if $maxlength}maxlength="{$maxlength}"{/if} />
   {if $comments}
   {$comments}
   {/if}
```